# Read multi page Tiff image and write to a pdf in Java

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox, tiff

I'm trying to convert a multi page tiff to a pdf using PDFBox and not been successful. I'm not able to use apache imaging-commons in the company as its not a stable release.

**Problem:** Not able to read a multi tiff and write to a pdf.

**Working solution so far:** Only the first page is getting written and saved to pdf. Also when a tiff is a single page, it works.

Below is the code:

```
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    log.info("Read Image");

    log.info("Process Image parts");

    //Get the number of pages
    int pages = 0;
    try(ImageInputStream imageInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/output/testpdf.tiff"))) {
        if (imageInputStream != null && imageInputStream.length() != 0) {
            Iterator<ImageReader> iteratorIO = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageInputStream);
            if (iteratorIO != null && iteratorIO.hasNext()) {
                ImageReader reader = iteratorIO.next();
                reader.setInput(imageInputStream);
                pages = reader.getNumImages(true);
                log.info("Number of pages in the tiff is " + pages);

            }
        }
    }
```

//Need a reader here for different page ?

```
        for (int i=0; i<pages; i++) {

        BufferedImage bimage = ImageIO.read(file);

        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        try {
            // the .08F can be tweaked. Go up for better quality,
            // but the size of the PDF will increase
            PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(doc, bimage, 0.08f);
            Dimension scaledDim = getScaledDimension(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()),
                    new Dimension((int) page.getMediaBox().getWidth(), (int) page.getMediaBox().getHeight()));
            contentStream.drawImage(image, 1, 1, scaledDim.width, scaledDim.height);
        } finally {
            contentStream.close();
        }
    }

    doc.save("src/main/resources/output/testpdf.pdf");
    doc.close();
```

Do I need to come up with a reader which is not provided by ImageIO?
OR
Do I need to split the tiff multi page to individual pages and then write to a pdf?

I've not worked with image manipulations much, but appreciate the level of quality the ImageIO after the conversion process!

Thanks

Comment: Please try `CCITTFactory.createFromFile(PDDocument document, File file, int number)`

Comment: What you're doing currently (compressing as a jpeg) is a bad idea because this compression is lossy. That makes sense mostly for photographs, not for scans of texts. Either use the CCITTFactory, or read the tiff images into BufferedImages (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770071/splitting-a-multipage-tiff-image-into-individual-images-java) and then use LosslessFactory.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr
Using CCITTFactory.createFromFile(PDDocument document, File file, int number) helped with the blocker. 
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try this, you need PDFBox jar and sun.jai.codec jar

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

import com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDecodeParam;

public class FinalTtoP {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    PDDocument document=new PDDocument();
    File file = new File("C:/nn.tif"); //Enter Tiff file path

    ImageInputStream isb = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);


    Iterator<ImageReader> iterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(isb);
    if (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()) 
    {
      throw new IOException("Image file format not supported by ImageIO: ");
    }

    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iterator.next();
    iterator = null;
    reader.setInput(isb);

    int nbPages = reader.getNumImages(true);


    System.out.println(nbPages);


    for(int p=0;p<nbPages;p++)
    {
      BufferedImage bufferedImage = reader.read(p);

      PDPage page = new PDPage();
      document.addPage(page);

      PDImageXObject i = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);

      PDPageContentStream content =new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
      content.drawImage(i, 0,0 ,page.getMediaBox().getWidth(),page.getMediaBox().getHeight());

      content.close();
    }
    document.save("C:/nnnnm.pdf"); //Enter path to save your file with .pdf extension
    document.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you using com.sun.media.jai.codec jar. I see all the import statements but they are never used in the code

Comment: I get this exception "Image file format not supported by ImageIO:" when I run. May be as I am using Java 8 and this code seems to be working from Java 9 onwards. Any alternative I can follow ?  I also tried following the below link, but that too is not working. It converts tiff to pdf but gives 'Insufficient data for an image' error when the PDF is tried to be opened - http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ImageToPDF.java.html

Comment: This link worked for me. I am successfully able to convert the tif to pdf.  - http://www.paulzepernick.com/java/java-apache-pdfbox-convert-multipage-tiff-to-pdf/

Comment: Previously I ran into exceptions like "Image file format not supported by ImageIO" , "Insufficient Data for an Image" , 
"Deprecated version of CCITTFactory.createFromRandomAccess" , "FillOrder 2 is not supported" , etc. 
Even I tried using iText (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ImageToPDF.java.html) 
but its cutting off the tiff content and not properly converting. But this link helped me out - http://www.paulzepernick.com/java/java-apache-pdfbox-convert-multipage-tiff-to-pdf/

Comment: I just posted the code implementation here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265241/2798816   . If somebody wants to refer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this code it will improve speed and it still slow then need to use itext.

```
public static byte[] convertTiffToPdf(File tiffFile) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream  = null;
    PDDocument document = null;
    ImageInputStream imgInputStream = null;
    try {

        outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        document = new PDDocument();
        PDRectangle pageSize = PDRectangle.LETTER;

        int noOfPages = 0;

        imgInputStream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(tiffFile);

        Iterator<ImageReader> iterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imgInputStream);
        if (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()) {
            throw new IOException("Image file format not supported by ImageIO: ");
        }
        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iterator.next();
        iterator = null;
        reader.setInput(imgInputStream);

        noOfPages = reader.getNumImages(true);
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfPages; i++) {
            PDPageContentStream content = null;
            try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = reader.read(i);

            PDPage page = new PDPage(pageSize);
            document.addPage(page);

            // PDImageXObject imgObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage); //Commented for PR 1028
            PDImageXObject imgObject = CCITTFactory.createFromFile(document, tiffFile, i); //PR 1028 
            
            //PDImageXObject imgObject = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);

            content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
            content.drawImage(imgObject, 0, 0, pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
            
            
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                content.close();
            }
        }

        document.save(outStream);
        byte[] fileBytes = outStream.toByteArray();

        return fileBytes;
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            document.close();
        }
        if (imgInputStream != null) {
            imgInputStream.close();
        }
        if (outStream != null) {
            outStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not improving speed by calling `reader.read(i)` despite not using the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CCITTFactory.createFromFile(PDDocument document, File file, int number)` which works for most bitonal tiff files. If that one doesn't work (because the TIFF file is tiled or in color), then read the individual pages into BufferedImage objects (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770071/splitting-a-multipage-tiff-image-into-individual-images-java)) and then use `LosslessFactory.createFromImage(PDDocument document, BufferedImage image)` with the result.